# Actionbar menu buttons not able to navigate to other Activities (Android)

Tags: java, android

I'm using a menu for the actionbar, and here is my xml mainactivity.xml under menus:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id = "@+id/Viewmain"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="VIEW"/>

    <item
        android:id = "@+id/Addmain"
        android:orderInCategory="205"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="ADD"/>


</menu>
```

Here is the code I used to navigate the buttons on the actionbar to other Activities in mainactivity.java:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




   }


    public boolean onContextItemSelected (MenuItem item)
    {

        if (item.getItemId()==200)
        {
            Intent myintent = new Intent(this, ViewStats.class );
            startActivity(myintent);
            return  true;
        }
        else if (item.getItemId()==205)
        {
            Intent myaddintent = new Intent(this,Sales.class );
            startActivity(myaddintent);

        }

        return  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


   public  boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
   {
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       this.myMenu = menu;


       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return  true;



   }
```

However when I click on the actionbar buttons "VIEW" & "ADD", no changes occur. What is wrong with my codes? Please help. (Note: No errors were shown on the stacktrace)

Comment: `onContextItemSelected` or it should be `onOptionsItemSelected`. Also remove `else` statement and keep just `if` and make sure you have inside `return true;` because compiler will go to the `super` execution.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see if execution is reaching your if statement?

Comment: @PeriHartman yeah i think it never reached that statement because nothing was shown on the debugger

Comment: ok. So, where do you call onContextItemSelected()? You need a hook somewhere.

Comment: i think u looking for options menu not context menu better u post menu creating code too also look at this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

Comment: @Peri Hartman You mean where i place the debugger? I placed it in the  'if' part. Btw i added some more codes in the question

Comment: Ah, you created an "options" menu but your hook is for a "context" menu. Here's a nice example someone wrote: https://www.javatpoint.com/android-option-menu-example

Comment: @PeriHartman Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to implement following methods to options menu

for creating menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);///here add your menu layout
    return true;
}
```

for select menu item this method need to implemented

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_game:
            newGame();
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            showHelp();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

don't add hard coded id comparison u can just add ur item id  by **R.id.yourid**